# In toplink and struts 2 based application, even after commiting data data disappears from the database

Tags: java, database, jpa, struts2, toplink-essentials

I have a struts 2 application and a toplink persistence provider running on tomcat 6.0.20 and a MySql 5.1.38 server on a GNU/Linux machine. After committing the data the when i go to retrieve it the data it has disappeared from the database.

I do a `em.commit()` and `em.flush()` after my queries have executed. How do they disappear? I am using all standard configuration files. I have reduced the `wait_timeout` and the `interactive_timout` period in mysql. Also am using `autoReconnectforPools` in my `persistence.xml`.

I also invalidate the cache on every users logout.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `em.commit()`? There is not such method on http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

Answer (score 1):

anyway it does not matter, the problem was solved by removing softweak from persistence.xml's entity type declaration and adding hardweak in its place.